# What is a typical system resource consumption for medium-large websites, like this one?

Tags: load, cpu-usage, ram

Well, I know it's more of dart-in-the-air type quesiton, but I am just trying to get a general idea. What would be an average system that you might need, in terms of number of CPUs (cores, GHz, etc), bandwith, RAM, storage, etc. to run some of the medium-large sites, such as this site or other websites (I want to say craigslist, but I know that their userbase is way larger), that may have anywhere from 1K to 10K users at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the correct answer to this sort of question is a moving target.  what might be true today will not be true in 10 years when hardware/software gets better.  And there will be a large variance in requisite hardware at any given time depending on how the system is implemented, and what tradeoffs the developers make, e.g. do they optimize for throughput or for getting up to the millisecond updates.  As a concrete example, when a badge is awarded, what delay is acceptable before the user sees their new badge?  1 second?  1 day?  The answer informs how the system is implemented, how much hardware you need, and what tradeoffs you can make.

The better question would be 'how to design software that is scalable from 1 to x users?'

Comment: Well, that question is even bigger than this one, but I am just trying to get an idea in todays terms. I understand that 10 years from now it might be different, but I am sure there are some hard core examples today that would give us a better idea of what to plan for.

Comment: Besides, software alone wouln't be scalable to X amount of users if your RAM, bandwith, etc. are limited, right? You can only brake your application down into so many pieces. But again, I am asking this question based strictly on hard data in todays terms. Any ideas?

Comment: @techexpert are you assuming a web application runs on one computer only?

Comment: @hvgotcoes, No, I am not, but if it is running on more than one, it would be good to know how many, cpu #s, RAM, etc.. I am really just trying to get a general idea here.

Comment: @techexpert, it runs the gamut.  A simple web application could run on a $500 machine you buy from dell.  A medium size one might have a loadbalancer in front of a few standard servers -- that type of setup could handle millions of requests a day if done correctly.  Google has *thousands* of servers all over the place.